# Get a value from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as follows:

```
var schMatrix = [
    ['Weight',100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000],
    ['Rate',395,413,484,560,635,691,763,837,910,982,1082,1155,1231,1304,1379,1452,1527,1570,1676,1750],
    ];
```

In my form the user would input a weight. What I am trying to do is if the weight is equal to or below the number in the weight part of the array that the corresponding rate is assigned to a variable.

Am stuck on how to do this. Any push in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would suggest you use a Object instead of a 2d-Array:

```
let schMatrix = {
    "Weight": [...,...,...],
    "Rate": [...,...,...]
}
```

Then you can itterate through the "Weight"-Array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < schMatrix["Weight"].length; i++) {
    if(schMatrix["Weight"][i] >= inputWeight){
        rate = schMatrix["Rate"][i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off using a map.  They are much faster and you can map each weight to a specific rate:

```
MAP = {
  100: 395,
  200: 413,
  300: 484,
  etc...
}

map.get(100) //outputs 395
```

To map the arrays to a map do the following:

```
let map = new Map();
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
   map.set(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}
```

Comment: This only works if it is exatly 100. 99 should output 395 as well.

Comment: True, missed that part.  Same idea with an object though

Answer (score 0):

```
var schMatrix = [
 ['Weight', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 
  1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000],
 ['Rate', 395, 413, 484, 560, 635, 691, 763, 837, 910, 982, 1082, 1155, 
  1231, 1304, 1379, 1452, 1527, 1570, 1676, 1750],
 ]

 function getRate(weight) {
   for (let i = 1; i < schMatrix[0].length; i++) {
     const currWeight = schMatrix[0][i]
     if (weight > currWeight) {
       // as soon as currWeight is bigger than weight, return
       return schMatrix[1][i-1]
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, if you assume the weights are sorted already.

```js
function getRate(matrix, target) {
  const [weights, rates] = matrix;
  for (let i = 1; i < weights.length; i++) {
    if (weights[i] > target) {
      return rates[i];
    }
  }
}

var schMatrix = [
  ['Weight',100,200],
  ['Rate',395,413],
];

const rate = getRate(schMatrix, 110);
console.log(rate); // 413
```

Comment: The first number in the array where 110 is equal to or less than is 200.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by finding the corresponding weights and rates columns via the `Array.prototype.find` method.  After that, check if the index plus one (because the label is the first item in the indexing) in "Weight" is less than or equal to the corresponding item in "Rate".  Here's the code:

```
const schMatrix = [
    ['Weight',100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000],
 ['Rate',395,413,484,560,635,691,763,837,910,982,1082,1155,1231,1304,1379,1452,1527,1570,1676,1750],
];

function weightLessThanEqRate(i) {
    const weights = schMatrix.find((item) => item[0] === "Weight");
    const rates = schMatrix.find((item) => item[0] === "Rate");
    return weights[i + 1] <= rates[i + 1];
}

console.log(weightLessThanEqRate(5));
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCyBDKAnAlgDxgXhgG0BYAKBgqIHIB1AU0wHMEoqAaARgAYu2AmHmwDMggCyCArIIBsggOyCAHIICcg7uo2cBvDiN3jdU3bN0Ldy3Wt46uAXTZlK1AEpo67ISoltRe34qibBKybNJCPtIqHGxy4WyKQnJs0bwqinycXBmcHBI+HHxCMXpcQXpyKpyiEpl5fMl5CpzScZxyUg5kdgDcZGQAZgCuYMBQmOAwAO4MzFAAMnQQEAAqCChgAKIAjm5QdAAUmABcMGBDALYARnToAJQwAN5OlKCQsDNMLBD4cIioGBwADoBpgwAATA5HfYXB54AB8MEwMMI9nweAIACJ6F8oJi7gBCPrkV7gaAwdDuH4EeDINBYbAgsGQ6F0WH4RHItmouzorF7Oj4okvCjoOhQIboMDTWbfQiYGAAahgHF5AB4CJT9hB5UqVb0yABffqkN4QEAAGzoQItIEYB0+c0WyzWGx2AoOEjudx6QA)